# PowerBI: Weekday or weekend

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a **table AW_Calendar**

```
Date                       Year    Month name   Day Name   weekend
Friday, January 1, 2016    2016    January        Friday     
Saturday, January 2, 2016  2016    January        Saturday
```

and so on

I am trying to write a **DAX** for whether a day is weekend or not, but I am getting an error

```
Weekend = if(AW_Calendar[Day Name]='Saturday'||'Sunday',1,0)
```

I am getting an error.

```
'Cannot find table 'Saturday''
```

What could be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` for strings. It uses the latter for table names.

Note that using the [WEEKDAY function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weekday-function-dax) may be more efficient here:

```
Weekend = IF ( WEEKDAY ( AW_Calendar[Date], 2 ) > 5, 1, 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use any logical operator you have to write the table name for every condition. Also ' character refers to tables. If you want to compare text data you have to use " instead of '. 
This should work:

```
Weekend = if(AW_Calendar[Day Name]="Saturday"|| AW_Calendar[Day Name]="Sunday",1,0)
```